# Is .NET open-source truly open-source if namespaces encapsulate core functionality?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, open-source

I have downloaded some **Open Source frameworks** with the intention of learning and ultimately contributing to them. Many times the framework **requires the use of a namespace** for which I do not have source code (e.g. Telerik.Web.MVC.UI), which brings me to my question.

Is a framework really open-source when namespaces provide core functionality? I can appreciate getting something for free but can't help question how this can be advertised as **"Completely Open Source"**?  Am I misunderstanding something about namespaces in .NET?

Comment: I agree with the suggestion to close this (my question). My suspicions were confirmed that not all open source is equal. When I asked this question, it was a genuine question as I was new to .NET and namespaces. I can see how the question could be interpreted otherwise. Thanks all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very common for open source code to rely on closed source components. For example any open source code relying on Microsoft .net relies on very large amounts of closed source code. In turn, any code that targets Windows itself depends on the closed source Windows code.

There's no conceptual difference between your examples and mine above.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what's really bugging you here is the fact that code relies on external *libraries*. The *namespace* is only a way of referencing them.

As for your actual question: Well. From the perspective of the programmers: They expose all code *they* have written. They cannot give rights to code they have only imported. However, the question of how collections of code of different "visibility" behave when they clash is in fact a strongly discussed one, see for example the difference between GPL (free software, everything derived will be free as well) and LGPL (free software, may be used in non-free software). This is a slightly different aspect, and it's also the "other direction" (from library to application)- still, just to say these are important questions.

As for your concrete case; it's probably ok to call it open source, but it might just mean that something being open source alone doesn't make it an interesting piece of source to look at ;)

Comment: +1  I appreciated learning about some of the controversy surrounding this subject, and that it is a strongly discussed subject, particularly when there are clashes between different collections of code. Your answer was enlightening, so thanks again.   Both answers helped me a lot and both were disappointing in the  respect that open source isn't really what I thought it was.